# Software Design Pattern for creating a simulator

Tags: java, design-patterns

My current task is to wait for a couple of fields from the backend (DB) and then modify them at my side. The backend changes will take time and in the meanwhile, I want to create a simulator and start of with my changes. Is there a design pattern, somebody can suggest, which will help me design a simulator for the backend and later on, without much code changes, allow me to port to the real backend values?

Comment: The article by Martin Fowler that Matt Ball mentioned here is brilliant. You should read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [mockito](http://mockito.org/), it is pretty great. The basics are:

```
ClassYouAreTesting fake = mock(ClassYouAreTesting.class);
when(fake.callsSomeMethod()).thenReturn(sampleData);
```

You may also need to use some [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) so that you can pass in real (during production) or mock (during testing) objects to functions.

Answer (score 4):

A stub should be sufficient.

> Stubs provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in for the test. Stubs may also record information about calls, such as an email gateway stub that remembers the messages it 'sent', or maybe only how many messages it 'sent'.

(From the Fowler article linked below)

Popular mocking frameworks for Java include:

- [jMock](http://www.jmock.org/)
- [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/)
- [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)

Other articles on mocking:

- [Approached to Mocking](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/02/11/mocks.html) (O'Reilly)
- [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) (Martin Fowler)

Comment: That was quick :) . Reading through it. Thank you Matt :)

Comment: Stub, not mock. You should read articles before you give them to others :) No offence.

Comment: @pavel: I have read the MF article, but it's been a while. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: No offence. The only thing that matters is the truth.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that fully emulates your collaborator is called *stub*. You can build it easy with bunch of frameworks: jMock, EasyMock, Mockito, etc.
Stub is not a design-pattern. It is a general idea for developing, testing and prototyping.